# CheckboxTreeViewer : hide a checked box

Tags: java, checkbox, jface, treeviewer

I use a CheckBoxTreeViewer and I want to hide a checked checkbox. I dont' know how to do that : when a check box is hidden, it's uncheckd too... Anyone have a solution ?

Thx

Comment: What do you mean by 'hide'?

Comment: I want to set invisible for the user a specific Checkbox (a line of the treeviewer) which is already checked. But wihtout uncheck the checkbox : I want that in the underlying model the corresponding element is checked. In other words, I want to handle the underlying model and its view separately.

Comment: You could use a `ViewFilter` to filter the rows from the tree.

Comment: Yes but when I filter a row, this row is automaticcaly unselected : so I lost the selection...